# Reordenar datos de un archivo de texto a columnas

Tags: python, textview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Necesito reordenar la data que tengo en un archivo de texto, todo está mezclado, sin separadores y no tengo el conocimiento para separar los datos por tipos en diferentes columnas, una columna para `str` y otra para `float`. El archivo es descomunalmente grande. ¿Cómo puedo gestionar este tipo de problemas?

1. El archivo inicial esta en *PDF*, su estructura más o menos es:

> `Ecode` | `Id` | `Name` | `salary` | `birthdate` | `income`

2. El problema es que luego hay otros datos aislados y desordenados en forma vertical, entre estos: `deducciones`, `deducciones SSO`, `impuestos` y otros...

Al pasar el archivo a texto con el *PDF to TXT*, se perdió la tabulación y el orden de los archivos, todo queda en una sola columna cuando lo paso a *Excel* (además es demasiado grande y pesado el archivo).

Comment: MRivas, te recomiendo que expongas el problema de forma concreta, es decir que incluyas un __[mcve]__. Ni siquiera sabemos de que estás hablando, si puedes usar _slices_, `split()`, etc. Simplemente _no está claro lo que preguntas_ por lo que tu pregunta corre el riego de ser cerrada. Usa este enlace __[edit]__.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] MRivas, como dice toledano necesitamos más datos para poder ayudarte, ejemplo mínimo del archivo de texto (para ver tipos de datos, estructura, etx), como quieres reordenarlos, salida esperada, posibilidad de usar librerias externas como Pandas, que has intentado hasta el momento, etc.  Ten en cuenta que con lo que proporcionas nosotros no sabemos nada, solo que quieres reordenar un archivo de texto que tiene algún tipo de datos con una estructura indefinida usando Python. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responder tan rapido, he tratado de abrir el archivo original con python para ver si mantiene la estructura, pero no consigo viusalizarlo con los modulos, intente con import PyPDF2  - pero da un error dice que no es un codigo binario

Comment: Es casi imposible poder ayudarte sin tener acceso alguno al archivo para ver como abordarlo. Debes mantener la estructura al pasarlo a rchivo de texto, manteniendo las tabulaciones o cambiandolas por comas para separar las columnas. El error con PyPDF2 puede deberse a que no abres el archivo en modo binario: `open(filename, 'rb')`. Sobre esto puedes poner el código que usas en la pregunta y el error y te ayudamos. Sobre extraer los datos es complicado sin tener acceso al pdf, si al menos pudieras compartir parte del pdf se podria intentar. ¿El pdf es todo datos en columnas separados por tabs?

Comment: Debes mostrar al menos una parte pequeña del archivo de texto. Un editor hexadecimal para poder visualizarlo puede ayudar para copiarlo. Con dos o tres columnas es más que suficiente.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, realmente no he tenido éxito ni subiendo la foto del archivo aca... intentare explicarme, tengo un archivo pdf, logre pasarlo a .txt  mantiene el orden espaciado(csv o tsv), sin embargo la tabla esta muy desorganizada y difiere por cada persona...

Comment: CODIGO
CEDULA
NOMBRE
CLASE
DENOMINACIÓN DE CARGO
ASIGNACIONES
DIAS
MONTO
GRADO
1.222
111222555
LEON TIGRE MATA YRUGE
1555
ANALISTA DE PERSONAL I
22
PII
02/04/1963
SUELDO INICIAL
COMPENSACION
TRANSPORTE
PRIMA ASISTENCIAL
HIJOS
ANTIGUEDAD
PROFESIONALIZACION

5.884,91
158,97
150,00
425,00
75,00
1.056,38
926,65
TOTAL Bs. ... estoy tratando con pandas de parsearlo pero me da mucho errores, ni siquiera logro visualizar el archivo tiene mas de 17000lineas y da muchos errores por no esperar tantas rows

Comment: Para subir una imagen solo tienes que ir al botón `editar` de tu pregunta (debajo de ella). En el editor seleccionas el botón que tiene las montañas y el sol (6º por la izquierda), en la ventana que aparce solo tienes que arrastra la imagen o hacer click en el centro y navegar por el explorador de archivos para seleccionarla. De todas formas es mejor que copies parte del txt tal y como está en tu archivo: haces lo mismo (botón editar), seleccionas parte del txt, lo pegas al final de la pregunta, lo seleccionas y pulsas Ctrl + k para que quede con el formato original.

Comment: Es importante que los datos que subas tengan exactamente el mismo formato que tienen en tu txt para poder reproducir el problema. Recuerda que si tiene datos personales protegidos debes enmascararlos adecuadamente en el ejemplo que subas (por ejemplo cambiando número de teléfono por 123456 o los nombres por otros inventados). Para que el archivo sea tratable debes conseguir que las filas ,aunque de diferente tamaños, tengan un separador entre columnas.La clave esta en conseguir esto desde el PDF, o bién desde una libreria o si hace falta tratando con la estructura interna del pdf directamente.